# Collecting different answers to a simple problem

Tags: education

I am collecting different answers to the problem below for possible publication in a pedagogical note I am writing. Please post freely (avoiding repetitions), and let your imagination go wild with alternative methods of solution. If I decide to quote one of your answers I will contact you for permission.

**Edited for clarity:**

> While driving on a loooong straight highway with no other traffic, your GPS shows that your current speed is $V+\varepsilon$, where $V$ is the official speed limit in MPH. this speed will remain constant in the problem. The GPS also displays an estimated time of arrival (ETA) to your destination which is $d/V$, where $d$ is the remaining distance (in practice, a real GPS usually adds corrections for traffic, stoplights, etc.) Notice that $d$ is unknown to you.
>
> Since you are driving faster than the speed used for the GPS estimate, this estimate will go down. Find a formula in terms of $V$ and $\varepsilon$ for the time (in minutes) that is needed to reduce the ETA by one minute.

Comment: The *time* needed?

Comment: Is this problem intended to be ambiguous?

Comment: A pedagogical note? About how to formulate math questions? >"While driving on a looong straight highway with no other traffic, your GPS displays your current speed $V+ε$, where $V$ is the official speed limit in MPH." The first thing that came to my mind was this: If I drive in a car and my display says "$V+ε$" I probably panic and die.

Comment: v=u+at, v^2-u^2=2as, s=ut+(1/2)a(t^2)

Comment: I have read my post a couple of times and do not find it ambiguous. Christian Blatter below go it right. I am asking for alternative ways to reach the same solution.

Comment: You said the current speed is V+eps, so shouldn't the ETA estimate already have changed? You should lay down the full assumption about ETA computation: The driver is currently driving at speed V. The ETA is what you expect. Suppose the driver instantaneously increases the speed to V+eps. How long until the ETA (which also changed instantaneously) reduces by a minute compared to the start of the problem? In fact, better to word the question without ETA at all!

Comment: @Evan: I hope this clarifies what I need :)

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez Ah now it's clear. So the GPS doesn't use your current speed in the ETA estimate.

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez  Hmm.. Think there is an additional confusion: You seem to want the moment the ETA of the GPS will display a minute less, and I provided that (unless I am missing something silly). But you said Christian Blatter's solution is correct?

Answer (score 3):

I interpret the problem as follows: Instead of driving at speed $V$ you drive at speed $V+\epsilon$ for a certain time span $t$ in order to make good a time amount $\Delta$ (one minute) on the ETA.

During this time span $t$ a certain distance $s$ is traveled. When driving at speed $V$ you would need the time amount $t+\Delta$  to travel this distance. Therefore we have the following equation:
$$(V+\epsilon)t=s=V(t+\Delta)\ .$$
Solving for $t$ we obtain
$$t={V\over\epsilon}\Delta\ .$$
Here $t$ and $\Delta$ are measured in minutes, while $V$ and $\epsilon$ are measured in miles per hour.

Comment: Thanks. This is straightforward. Now I'm hoping to see other solutions that have some 'twist' to how the setting is thought about.

Comment: This is probably the intended interpretation, but then the original question should reflect that. I was trying to find this kind of interpretation that gives a simple answer, so this is nice!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're collecting solutions, here's a different way to look at this problem. Since you want to arrive at a time $\Delta$ sooner than the GPS thinks you will, you can pretend you had a head start of $\Delta$ and traveled at velocity $V$. In reality, you started without that lead and traveled at a rate of $V+\epsilon$. Graph the actual and imagined positions together and you're looking for where the two lines cross (i.e., when the distances are the same). Doing so, you'll get this picture
[image]

where the red line is the actual situation and the blue line is the imagined situation. Of course, the intersection time is exactly what Christian found, $t = V\Delta/\epsilon$.

Comment: ok so we still have two different interpretations for the what the question asks . What you and Christian have at the end is the actual time traveled to the destination given the information in the problem. I have the time it takes for the GPS estimates, which for some reason only uses the speed limit of the road, to drop by 1 minute. so maybe the OP can clarify once again what is desired...

Answer (score 1):

We want to reach our destination $\delta$ units earlier in time. Let $t$ denote the time period for which we should travel at speed $V+\epsilon$. This means that we can travel an extra distance of $t\cdot\epsilon$ before reaching our destination. If we travel the distance $V\delta$ beforehand, we'll reach our destination $\delta$ units of time earlier. Thus, $t\epsilon=V\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

So the ETA given the distance remaining $d$ will show $d/V*60$ minutes where $d$ is unknown to us.

Given time $t$ (in minutes), we reduce the distance by $(V+\epsilon)t/60$.

The ETA at time $t$ would show $\frac{d - (V+\epsilon)t/60}{V}*60$.

Comparing the two ETA's, the difference is $(V+\epsilon)t/V$ which setting to $1$ minute, shows that $t = \frac{V}{V+\epsilon}$ (in minutes).

Answer (score 0):

When ETA=T speed should is $V+\epsilon$, So with ETA=$T-1$ speed should be $\Large \frac{(T-1)(V+\epsilon)}{T}...(1)$

Speed=distance/time $\Rightarrow \Large S=\frac{D}{t}$

$\therefore \Large T=\frac{D}{V+\epsilon}$ and $\Large (T-1)=\frac{D}{V+\epsilon}-1$

$\therefore$ from eqn(1) Speed=$\Large \frac{D-1}{V+\epsilon}\frac{V+\epsilon}{D}(V+\epsilon)$

$\Large (1-\frac{1}{D})(V+\epsilon)$

for large D, speed=$\Large V+\epsilon$

so with the same speed you can reach your destination one minute earlier!

Comment: The last comment is a funny one, as you don't get to the destination one "earlier", you are only one minute closer to your destination compared to the start of the problem :)